# Is GUID written to disk drive?

Tags: guid

Is the GUID for a storage volume on an external hard drive written to the drive or is it generated and stored on the OS where the GUID partition table was created? I want to know if the GUID is the same for a given volume when mounted on different operating systems and/or machines.

Comment: I'd expect it to be on the drive, but isn't this easily testable, empirically?

Comment: Yes, it is testable. But, I was surprised that I couldn't find any answer/explanation in web searches. I was hoping for a description of how GUID is implemented (and stored?) on storage volumes.

Comment: If it was stored solely by the OS, then how would it know which drive it belongs to? Oh.. yes. it would need a long, pseudo-random number on the drive to compare to. What should we call that, I wonder? What would it do if the drive had been reformatted on another computer? [sorry, but this just seems so obvious] See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier GUIDs don't just belong to hard drives.

Comment: What “GUID of a storage volume” anyway? Do you mean the GPT partition id? Or the filesystem-specific unique identifier?

Comment: @Tetsujin, it is not at all clear to me from:
"The "partition label" and the "partition UUID" are both stored in the superblock. They are both part of the file system rather than of the partition. For example, ext2–4 contain a UUID, while NTFS or FAT32 do not.

The superblock is a part of the file system, thus fully contained within the partition, hence if you do a dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1, both sda1 and sdb1 will have the same label and UUID."

Comment: @Tetsujin, why would a GUID need to be stored on the drive to avoid conflicts? Why couldn't the OS generate a UUID/GUID for a drive every time it is mounted?

Comment: What on earth would be the point of an **identifier** that didn't identify? I block drives from mounting per OS, per GUID, so if I boot to one OS, one set of drives mounts, to another & I get a different set of drives. That wouldn't work if they were just randomly assigned every time.

Comment: @osprey What part is not clear? You could always look up terms that you don't know with a search engine of your choice, as these terms are usually, well.. globally unique.

Comment: But in the first place, _which_ "GUID for a storage volume" are you asking about? There can be no less than four different GUIDs associated with a volume, filesystem, or partition, some of which are stored on disk, and some which aren't. Are you asking about GPT GUIDs, or about filesystem GUIDs, or about Windows `\\?\Volume` GUIDs?

Comment: @mashuptwice, great so LMGTFY? Is that it?

Comment: @user1686, "There can be no less than four different GUIDs associated with a volume, filesystem, or partition, some of which are stored on disk, and some which aren't"<<<
This. This is the part that I find confusing. Which of these GUIDs would be appropriate to share with someone else so that they can positively identify which among a collection of HDD devices contains the subset of information/data they want to retrieve?

Comment: @osprey no, just avoiding to write a whole textbook about every paragraph you ask. It is all in the wikipedia article, Disk GUID, partition type and unique partition GUID are in LBA. Exception is the the disks WWN, which could sit on some flash or eeprom, depending on how the manufacturer implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information in the question to give a full answer.

However, if the question is about a partition's GUID,
then the answer is
that it's stored in the partition table and relates to the
[GUID Partition Table (GPT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table).

In the GPT disk format, each partition has two GUIDs:

- The GUID that identifies its type, such as EFI partition
- The GUID that identifies uniquely this partition and is its unique
  reference.

Comment: This does answer the question I was trying to ask, even if that's not the same as the question I posted. So thanks for that. So what other GUIDs/UUIDs are written to the partitions/filesystems on a HDD? It seems that this may depend on filesystem flavor? I'm not being deceptively naive, I've just never had much interest in computer hardware.

Comment: You will find this information in the link I gave, where every bit in the GPT tables is described.

Comment: Yes, it is helpful for understanding partition GUIDs. I'm struggling with understanding which of various unique identifiers are being returned by OS utilities.

Comment: All of them can be accessed, but the one that uniquely identifies this partition is especially useful because it can be used in commands to address the partition, and is also copied into the registry (again, to identify the partition).